# how to add a column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas, and when I do print(df), the result says as follows:

```
                        open      high       low     close        volume
2021-01-26 09:00:00  0.000230  0.000236  0.000228  0.000228    303.813500
2021-01-27 09:00:00  0.000226  0.000230  0.000223  0.000230   1479.338775
[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

The problem is that the very first date column has no name and seems not to be regarded as an actual column (it says it has only 5 columns). How can I put a name on the first column?

Comment: That's index, use `df.index` to access it.

Comment: The first column is probably the index. Use `df = df.rename_axis(index="datetime")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column in this case seems like an `index`
You can set a name for the `index` using

```
df.index.name = 'date'
```

It can be used as a column if use

```
df.index.name = 'date'
df = df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the lef-most column is the index. You can set a name via:

```
df.index.name = 'my_pretty_name'
```